# iSCSI LIO target - how to resize lun?

Tags: linux, scsi, iscsi

What are the steps to resize a lun which is currently attached to an initiator? I mostly interested to know how to do that for file-based luns.

Comment: In this script which doesn't rely on targetcli: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/target/target-export-device . At one step it writes the LUN size. Maybe you could do some tests to see how this dynamically behaves on the target side. Then there's still the other problem of how the initiator can detect a change was done.